# Is there a way to know the actual size of a word with a given font?

Tags: java, kotlin, fonts, apache-poi, awt

I made a program that replace all the words in PPTX with latin words that have the same number of letter
The issue is that words don't have the same physical size because of the different distribution and size of each characters inside of it.
So I need a way to know / estimate the actual size of a word with a given font to replace it with another latin words with a close size.
The program is in Kotlin and I use Apache POI XSLF library

I found that the AWT Java library can estimate the actual physical size but I don't think I can extract the actual font file using Apache POI XSLF library to use it with AWT Java library

Comment: Potentially unhelpful comment, but if you restrict your fonts to only use Monospaced fonts, you can avoid this problem entirely. All characters in a Monospaced font have the exact same width - by definition. I understand if that is not an option for you though.

Comment: Do you have the font referenced in the PPTX file installed on the machine running the program?

Comment: @davidalayachew Thanks for the idea but I sadly can't do that, the presentation was made with that font in mind and changing it to anonymize will negatively affect the design in mind

Comment: @Gagravarr I don't think, the program will be hosted in Railway and some presentations uses paid / custom fonts BUT the fonts should be embedded inside the PPTX File, we always have that option on for all presentations